# Drupal 8 constanly hangs and fails installing plugin

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

First, I am a newbie in drupal, and I still haven't managed this framework.

I am running Drupal 8 in localhost, and I can edit my pages. But, constantly I need to restart Drupal because if suddenly hangs. I tried to look at the logs, but I can't find any information about this behavior. It seems that the server has stopped responding. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

[image: general-logs]

Also, I am trying to install the plugin `ds-8.x-3.5.tar.gz` in Drupal, and I get this error.

[image: installation error]

[image: update manager error]

[image: more detailed error]

I know this is not a useful debug information, but this is what I have. I can't understand why this plugin is not installed. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some dependency issues.

As you state in your question that you would like to install ds-8.x-3.5.tar.gz I deduce that you are the dependencies manager. Since it looks like you're trying to install the module manually. You can install the module and manage the dependencies manually but it can be a pain.

Better to leave that to a piece of software designed to manage all the complex dependencies Drupal has and use composer as a dependency manager.

To install composer follow this link: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

If you can, start a new Drupal install and read the docs about installing Drupal with composer: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies
follow the section under heading: `Using drupal/recommended-project`
That is much easier than converting your existing install to composer.

But if you need to convert your existing install follow the section under heading: `Managing existing sites using Composer`

Once you have composer running and have installed Drupal with it. You can simply run: `composer require drupal/ds` and your module is installed with all the needed dependencies .